# flutter : freezed required nor marked with @Default

Tags: flutter, freezed, flutter-freezed

I am trying to use freezed on my application, So I added

```
environment:
  sdk: ">=2.7.0<3.0.0"

  freezed: ^0.14.0
  freezed_annotation: ^0.14.0
```

to my dependencies.

```
dev_dependencies:
  freezed_annotation: ^0.12.0
  build_runner:  ^2.0.1
  retrofit_generator:
  flutter_localizations:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
```

After that I create simple freezed class :

```
import 'package:freezed_annotation/freezed_annotation.dart';

part 'chart_daily_expanded_detailes_model.freezed.dart';

@freezed
abstract class ChartDailyExpandedDetailesModel
    with _$ChartDailyExpandedDetailesModel {
  const factory ChartDailyExpandedDetailesModel({
    String title,
    String testNumber,
    String testPercentage,
    String icon,
  }) = _ChartDailyExpandedDetailesModel;
}
```

But I got this error:

```
[SEVERE] freezed:freezed on lib/new_develop/model/test/chart_daily_expanded_detailes_model.dart:

The parameter `title` of `ChartDailyExpandedDetailesModel` is non-nullable but is neither required nor marked with @Default
package:app/new_develop/model/test/chart_daily_expanded_detailes_model.dart:9:12
  ╷
9 │     String title,
```

this is flutter doctor:

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.2.3, on Linux, locale en_US.UTF-8)
[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.3)
    ✗ Android license status unknown.
      Run `flutter doctor --android-licenses` to accept the SDK licenses.
      See https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/linux#android-setup for more details.
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Android Studio (version 4.2)
[✓] Android Studio
[✓] VS Code (version 1.60.0)
[✓] Connected device (2 available)

! Doctor found issues in 1 category.
```

My project is not null safety and I want to use freezed in non null safety state.

Comment: Well it seems that your project IS null-safety. If you change it to `String? title;` that error will go away. But then I predict that `testNumber`, `testPercentage` and `icon` will all receive the same error and can be fixed the same way. Or you add a default, non-null value for each one: `String title = ""`;

Comment: My project is not null safety @daddygames

Answer (score 6):

Add `required` before items, or you can make it nullable using `String?` or provide default value like  `@Default("") String icon,`

```
@freezed
abstract class ChartDailyExpandedDetailesModel
    with _$ChartDailyExpandedDetailesModel {
  const factory ChartDailyExpandedDetailesModel({
    required String title,
    required String testNumber,
     String? testPercentage, //nullable item
    @Default("") String icon, //contain default value
  }) = _ChartDailyExpandedDetailesModel;
}
```

Comment: My project is not null safety and my sdk is 2.7 so I got this error https://pasteboard.co/KjvyLfC.png

Comment: can you try `freezed: ^0.12.7`

Comment: I got a lot of error about conflict because I am using almost last version of libraries and when I use freezed   `^0.12.7` , It's make a lot of conflict.

Comment: How about removing version number, btw `0.12.7` is not using  null-safety but there `build` label status is `faling` and I'm not sure about it’s root.

Comment: I did before but Still I got `non-nullable but is neither required nor marked with @Default` error

Comment: build_runner:  ^2.0.1 is using `null safety` try `<=2.0.0`

Comment: If I'm not wrong, `reflectable>=3.x` is also using nullsafety

Comment: You can try removing all version number do `flutter clean` and rebuild may help

Answer (score 0):

This would give me the same error:

```
const factory FamilyModel(
    int page,
    int per_page,
    int pages,
    int total_items,
    @Default([]) List<FamilyMemberModel> familyMembers,
  ) = _FamilyModel;
```

But in this way I fixed it:

```
const factory FamilyModel(
    int page,
    int per_page,
    int pages,
    int total_items, {
    @Default([]) List<FamilyMemberModel> familyMembers,
  }) = _FamilyModel;
```

In substance, the @Default param must be in between the `{ }` so that the compiler knows that it's optional and (in that case) can be replaced by `@Default([])`

Comment: Well done Leonardo!